# Every day a student solves one, two or three problems. Find the number of distinct ways

Tags: combinatorics

> Every day a student solves one, two or three problems. Find the number of distinct ways
>
> a) he solves problems in 30 days,
>
> b) he solves 50 problems,
>
> c) he solves 50 problems in 30 days

Answer. For part A I guess We will say there are three option for the first day 1, 2 or 3 and second day it will go on like that the answer is $3^{20}$. But for part B and part C I couldn't think anything Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. As regards b) note that if for $d_i$ days he solves $i$ problems for $i=1,2,3$ then $d_1+2d_2+3d_3=50$ and this can be done in
$$\frac{(d_1+d_2+d_3)!}{d_1!\cdot d_2!\cdot d_3!}.$$
For c) we have another constraint: $d_1+d_2+d_3=30$.

P.S. Generating function approach. The answers for b) and c) are given respectively by ([WA-link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%201%2F(1-(x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3)),%7Bx,0,50%7D%5D))
$$[x^{50}]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(x+x^2+x^3)^{k}=[x^{50}]\frac{1}{1-(x+x^2+x^3)},$$
and ([WA-link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%20(x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3)%5E(30),%7Bx,0,50%7D%5D))
$$[x^{50}]((x+x^2+x^3)^{30}).$$

Comment: could you explain what you did in B part ?

Comment: Do you mean the generating function approach? Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9FFBXBccow

Comment: Not for generating function I said for part B.

Comment: btw thanks for video I will watch it.

Comment: As regards b) I gave you a hint.  Find all non-negative integer solutions of $d_1+2d_2+3d_3=50$ and add all contribuitions $\frac{(d_1+d_2+d_3)!}{d_1!\cdot d_2!\cdot d_3!}$.

Comment: okay okay I got it thanks for your help

Comment: @Manzara Have you the answers for b) and c)?

Comment: No the method is enough for me. The important thing is idea. And I got the idea